# Error in requiring jquery

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on react 0.14 using es6. Facing an issue while requiring jquery.

```
//loading jquery
import jQuery from 'jquery';
$ = jQuery

import './libs/bootstrap.min.js'
```

This gives the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery.

Any idea?

Comment: Upon import jQuery sets `window.$` and `window.jQuery` by itself, even if it is loaded as an AMD module. So it should work. I suggest producing a [mcve] so that people who might help you know precisely what it is you are starting from.

Comment: @Louis thank you. Will do that surely.

Answer (score 0):

I guess es6 imports are hoisted to the top of the file, and bootstrap is looking for the `$` variable.

Can you try:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import './libs/bootstrap.min.js'
```